# How to create a docker container from an image

Tags: nvidia, docker, cuda, 21.10

I have the following image:

```
REPOSITORY               TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch   18.04-py3   c3555fec4fe6   3 years ago   5.9GB
The goal is to use Ubuntu 18.04 with CUDA 10.2.
```

Now I want to create a container with this image. These are the commands I've tried:

`docker image tag nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:18.04-py3 pytorch`

`docker run pytorch`

But this is the error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: 
mkdir /var/lib/docker/containers/22346b8352726ee06780791c3ee37c138b8c4b3d600225502266916e57902c56: 
no such file or directory.
```

Comment: You should [edit] the question, post a link to the guide or guides you tried and explain what went wrong or you didn't understand.

Comment: I added more details..

Answer (score 0):

For tag the image clone and run that try this:

> List the images

```
# docker images
REPOSITORY                           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         
SIZE
jupyter/datascience-notebook         latest    f5573d8505f2   4 months ago    4.14GB
centos                               latest    5d0da3dc9764   6 months ago    231MB
```

> Tag your image and check the new clone

```
[root@local ~]# docker tag centos:latest centos_1:clone
[root@local ~]# docker images
REPOSITORY                           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
jupyter/datascience-notebook         latest    f5573d8505f2   4 months ago    4.14GB
centos                               latest    5d0da3dc9764   6 months ago    231MB
centos_1                             clone     5d0da3dc9764   6 months ago    231MB
```

> Run the clone image as a container

```
[root@local ~]# docker run -it 5d0da3dc9764 bash
[root@99d655eb9ef0 /]#
```